# libgdx sprite position relative to body

Tags: sprites, box2d, libgdx, body

Apologies if this is a reiteration, as I couldn't find another discussion of this over the past couple days.

***Issue:***
I'm using libgdx and box2d, and I'm currently updating the sprite's position to the body's current position every render call. Using a debugRenderer to see the bodies, I see that there is fairly noticeable lag between the movement/position of the body and the sprite that is being moved relative to it.

***Question:***
Is this lag normal, possibly to perform collisions ahead of time? If not, should I be manipulating/relating the positions differently?

Thanks in advance!

**[Solution]**
This was a coding error on my part. Pointed out by a good reply below, I was updating the position of the sprite relative to the body and then stepping the physics. Thus never actually setting the sprite to the body's CURRENT position. Thanks!

Comment: No the lead is not normal. Are you updating box2d first and then sprites position afterwards?

Comment: Are you updating your physics world in your render loop?  You might need to implement a fixed timestep for the physics update as well. It's difficult to tell what's wrong without posting code.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies, will look into both of these when I get the chance and post back as to if either was the problem. I think it might be ClassicThunder's post that is on the right track. I think I inadvertently set sprite position to body, then stepped the physics! Thus never having them in the same spot...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Solution] This was a coding error on my part. Pointed out by a good reply above, I was updating the position of the sprite relative to the body and then stepping the physics. Thus never actually setting the sprite to the body's CURRENT position. Thanks!

Comment: If this fix worked for you, please accept your own answer to show that it was resolved.